# Creating a popup menu at runtime

Tags: delphi, popup, contextmenu

I'm trying to simply create a popup menu (or context menu), add some items to it, and show it at the mouse location. All the examples I have found are doing this using the designer. I'm doing this from a DLL plugin, so there is no form/designer. The user will click a button from the main application which calls the `execute` procedure below. I just want something similar to a right click menu to appear.

My code obviously doesn't work, but I was hoping for an example of creating a popup menu during runtime instead of design time.

```
procedure TPlugIn.Execute(AParameters : WideString);
var
  pnt: TPoint;
  PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
  PopupMenuItem : TMenuItem;
begin
  GetCursorPos(pnt);
  PopupMenuItem.Caption := 'MenuItem1';
  PopupMenu1.Items.Add(PopupMenuItem);
  PopupMenuItem.Caption := 'MenuItem2';
  PopupMenu1.Items.Add(PopupMenuItem);
  PopupMenu1.Popup(pnt.X, pnt.Y);

end;
```

Comment: @Warren there are of statically typed languages for which declaring a variable is enough to initialise it. C++ is the obvious example.

Comment: @ike expect problems with GUI code in plugin DLLs.

Comment: -1 for "My code obviously doesn't work". Always describe the failure with error message reproduced verbatim

Comment: "My code obviously doesn't work". Why, oh why? Seems like you dó know the answer! Why ask then?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Can you post a link to some resource that would explain "expect problems with GUI code in plugin DLLs" ? thanks

Comment: @Rigel It's why packages exist.Using a DLL instead of a package for your plugin means that the DLL has a separate instance of the VCL to the host executable. Classic symptoms are that type identity does not work as expected. 
For instance, in the code above `TPopupMenu` is a different type in the DLL from the exact same named type in the host because there are distinct VCL instances. But there are many more problems. If packages aren't a viable option, then you need to do a bit more work to enable plugins.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to actually create instances of a class in Delphi before you can use them. The following code creates a popup menu, adds a few items to it (including an event handler for the click), and assigns it to the form. Note that you have to declare (and write) the `HandlePopupItemClick` event yourself like I've done).

In the interface section (add `Menus` to the `uses` clause):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    // Double-click the OnCreate in the Object Inspector Events tab. 
    // It will add this item.
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    // Add the next two lines yourself, then use Ctrl+C to
    // generate the empty HandlePopupItem handler
    FPopup: TPopupMenu;      
    procedure HandlePopupItem(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

// The Object Inspector will generate the basic code for this; add the
// parts it doesn't add for you.
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TMenuItem;
  i: Integer;
begin
  FPopup := TPopupMenu.Create(Self);
  FPopup.AutoHotkeys := maManual;
  for i := 0 to 5 do
  begin
    Item := TMenuItem.Create(FPopup);
    Item.Caption := 'Item ' + IntToStr(i);
    Item.OnClick := HandlePopupItem;
    FPopup.Items.Add(Item);
  end;
  Self.PopupMenu := FPopup;
end;

// The Ctrl+C I described will generate the basic code for this;
// add the line between begin and end that it doesn't.
procedure TForm1.HandlePopupItem(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(TMenuItem(Sender).Caption);
end;
```

Now I'll leave it to you to figure out how to do the rest (create and show it at a specific position).

Comment: i created and showed the context menu all in the same procedure. i don't need to free anything correct?

Comment: I can't answer that, because I don't know what you did exactly. In the code I posted, the menu belongs to the form (`TPopupMenu.Create(Self)` in a form method means the form is the owner, and is responsible for freeing it) and the individual items belong to the menu ('TMenuItem.Create(FPopup)`). Your menu will have to exist long enough for the event handler to still be valid when an item is clicked.

Comment: What I would probably do is have the plugin create the popup menu in it's constructor. `Execute` would then just get the cursor position and display the menu at that position, and the destructor of the plugin could free the popup menu. I don't know if that will work for you, because I don't have any information other than what you posted in your question.

Comment: yes, sorry for the lack of detail, part of it trying to figure out what and how to describe. but adding the `destructor` and adding `FPopup.Free;` worked. until then, my application was consistently crashing. thanks.

Comment: I can not understand people being so aggressive when issuing comments like the one by `Warren P`. Where is that arrogance comming from? They forget that they where newbies once and had made the same basic errors. If you don't have the necessary pacience to deal with that basic questions, I think is better not to make comments. Take an example from `Ken White` who's answer was straight, simple, objective and actually helped the user to solve its problem.

Comment: also FPopUp.CreateMenuItem should work